# Why does Suspend/Resume fail to render desktop upon signing in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, dell, suspend

My machine is a Dell Latitude E6510 with Ubuntu 14.04 installed.

Whenever I Suspend, either by clicking the suspend button from the system menu or by closing the laptop, and then resume, the log-in screen appears.

For about 10 seconds, everything is frozen except mouse movement. I can move the mouse but I can't click on anything, can't enter text, and the mouse doesn't change to acknowledge hovering over particular elements like a text input for instance.

Eventually, control is restored to me, then when I enter my password and log in, the screen displays just my desktop background image, the message 'System problem encountered' sometimes flashes briefly, and then disappears. Then, the screen remains just my desktop background image and I cannot do anything but restart my machine.

Any help would be appreciated! I will provide more specs if anybody believes they are relevant to this issue.

[image]

Comment: When that happens, try to open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T. If it works see if using `unity --replace` restores the interface.

Comment: I can't open a terminal when this error occurs. It seems as though the machine is frozen entirely except for mouse control.

Comment: Does that laptop has some hybrid graphics like Optimus? If yes what is the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep -E "bumblebee|prime|bbswitch"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for the issue. Under 'power' settings, I found an option entitled 'When the lid is closed' and selected 'Do Nothing' instead of suspend. I also removed the suspend option from the system menu. While this is un-ideal (as closing the lid doesn't shut off my system) it still turns off the screen, and upon resume, my system does not crash. So I'm going with this option for now.

Answer (score 0):

if you can access to the terminal

CTRL+ALT+F1

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove ubuntu-desktop 
$ sudo apt-get autoremove unity 

$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install unity-2d 
$ sudo apt-get install unity
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop 
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
$ sudo shutdown -r
```

after the reboot's done CTRL+ALT+F1 again & reset your unity

```
$ setsid unity
```

Comment: Did you mean 'autoremove ubuntu' in the first command instead of 'autoremove-ubuntu'? Autoremove-ubuntu with the dash in between the words came up as an invalid command. Or.. autoremove ubuntu-desktop?

Comment: oh sorry my bad autoremove ubuntu-desktop

Comment: I performed the commands you gave me, and the problem is persisting. I believe your commands were a way to recycle the unity desktop environment,but my error is a complete freeze of the screen upon login after suspending.

Comment: Another detail: if I log out of my account, close my laptop to put it to sleep, then re-open it, the same problem happens. It's as though the action of putting my system to sleep breaks Ubuntu

Comment: can you post a picture ?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/dJkQkpm.jpg

Comment: try to open the tty 
(ctrl+alt+F1)
then restart the display manager $ sudo service lightdm restart

Comment: I restarted display manager and tried sleep/suspend.. my machine froze for about 15 seconds then a black screen flashes and I was back to the login screen. I restarted the display again in TTY and logged back in, same blank screen freeze error as in the image I posted.